# Extracting key of specific type in generic

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a generic class Foo where DateKey is in keyof T and indicates a date field in T. My first approach has been thus:

```
abstract class Foo<T extends { [P in DateKey]: Date }, DateKey extends keyof T> {
  abstract get dateKey(): DateKey // Subclasses implement this
  constructor(x: T) {
    const z = x.foo;
    // z is a Date
  }
}
```

What I'd like is for `x[this.dateKey]` to be typed as a `Date`, with no other fields accessible on `x` (i.e. to all other purposes it is unknown/any). However what happens in practice is that `x.anything` is typed as a Date and I can access any property.

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, and/or how I can achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: `T` is defined to be an object that has any key-value pairs, as long as each value is a `Date`. So it seems to make sense that you can access `T.anything`, and `T.anything` should be a `Date`. It also seems to make sense that `T[DateKey]` evaluates to a `Date`.

Comment: My guess about why it's happening: inside the implementation of `Foo`, the compiler doesn't know what `T` or `DateKey` will be, so it (probably) treats them as the widest types they can be... that is, they equal their constraints.  This isn't really type safe but it's what happens.  So `DateKey` is taken to be `keyof T`, and `T` is taken to be `Record<keyof T, Date>`, which is likely widened to `{[k: string]: Date}`.  From outside `Foo`, once you instantiate `T` and `DateKey`, the compiler will behave as you expect, I think.

Comment: What are you doing with `T`, by the way?  Would you be able to just use ```abstract class Foo<DK extends string> {      abstract get dateKey(): DK;
      constructor(x: Record<DK, Date>) { }    }``` ?

Comment: @jcalz T is a database record - I'd like to be able to access the date field on T, as well as construct queries for my ORM of the form `{[this.dateKey]: something}`. In your example, what's Record<>?

Comment: `Record<K, V>` is in the standard TypeScript library... it's basically just `{[P in K]: V}`.  So you only care about a single property from `T`?  What are you doing to `x` in the constructor?  Are you saving it anywhere in the object?